# MVC (Spring): Logic Organisation Entity and Service

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have a simple question about code organisation.

- TeamRepository (Repository Class)
- TeamService (Service Class)
- Team (Entity Class)

I want to set a new team leader for an team object. Should this function "setLeader(User user)" in the Entity Class or better in the TeamService Class?

```
team.setLeader(user);
teamService.save(team);
```

or

```
teamService.setLeader(team, user);
```

Inside the "setLeader" Function there is a if condition (if user is a team member) then declare the user as the new team leader.

I guess it's ok in the entity class or? I am confused because i have read that "business logic" should not be in entity classes.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly keep in mind that:

### Entity Class:

In a good designed architecture, it should be just like a POJO class, containing simple attributes, default constructor, their getter() & setters() and other optional methods like toString() & equal() etc.
Example:

```
@Entity
public Class Team{
    private String id;
    private User leader;

    public Team(){}
    //getters & setters
}
```

### Repository Class:

This main purpose of this class should be either save, update, delete or retrieve simple record from a database, no business logic.

### Service Class:

This is the class where you can specify all business/ domain related logic here. It should populate required entity object, and then call specific repository class to save given entity.

```
@Service
public class TeamService{
    @Autowired
    TeamRepository repo;

    public void createTeam(){
       Team team = new Team();
       if(//user is the member of team){
          team.setLeader(user);//assume user object is already initialized
       }
       repo.save(user);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since leader is a attribute of your Team-class, leader should be directly manipulated with the setter-method of your Team-class. That's my opinion/feeling.

There is no higher logic or computation behind the action. It's just setting the value of the entity's attribute.